# ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libass.so.5

Tags: ffmpeg, youtube-dl

I'm using youtube-dl, on Ubuntu 16.04 desktop, to fetch a video and it will fail after downloading the audio and video files, with the error message:

```
ERROR: ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libass.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

However, when I run:

```
sudo apt-get install libass5
```

I get the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libass5 is already the newest version (0.13.6-1~xenial1).
```

What else do I need to do?

Comment: What's in... `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu`?

Comment: @bc2946088 over 2000 things. Can you give me a grep you want? E.g.  these are all the files beginning with `libass` :  `libass.so.9`, `libass.so.9.0.0`, `libassuan.so.0`, `libassuan.so.0.7.2`

Comment: I was meaning with libass*.  Just throwing this out there... `ln -s libass.so.9 libass.so.5`  Then try your youtube-dl again.

Comment: Thanks that worked. So if you just put the answer with the commands `cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu` `sudo ln -s libass.so.9.0.0 libass.so.5` I'll mark it as the answer

Comment: Weird you are getting those errors. Are you using the youtube-dl package from Ubuntu repositories ? You can also download the youtube-dl binary directly from the youtube-dl website. When you have that you can run it from the current directory, and also let it update (There are very often updates!) like this : ./youtube-dl -U   The downloaded binary seems statically compiled : ldd -v ./youtube-dl  "not a dynamic executable", so that could be a quick fix.

Comment: I've been doing `sudo pip install --upgrade youtube-dl`

Comment: Symlinking is a messy solution, but I can't duplicate this issue to suggest a better alternative. What's your `youtube-dl` command?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard `youtube-dl -f 'bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/mp4' https://youtu.be/Gm9PjldJFqo` Maybe this is just a one off due to the way I have set up my desktop and won't happen again.

Comment: Still can't duplicate the issue, but as you said it's probably a corner case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears as though ffmpeg is calling up a library for which you have a newer version, though still libass5.

Creating a symlink linking the library file ffmpeg is looking for to the file you have.

```
cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo ln -s libass.so.9 libass.so.5
```